# jest comparing objects . string

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript, jestjs

I receive this result in a Jest

```
result1 -> {
        "partyRoleIdentifier": {
          "internalEmployeeIdentifier": {
            "id": "id-modified"
          }
        }
      }
```

I make this comparision:

```
expect(result).toBe('{\"partyRoleIdentifier\": {\"internalEmployeeIdentifier\": {\"id\": \"id-modified\"}}}');
```

but I got this result:

```
 Expected: "{\"partyRoleIdentifier\": {\"internalEmployeeIdentifier\": {\"id\": \"id-modified\"}}}"
    Received: {"partyRoleIdentifier": {"internalEmployeeIdentifier": {"id": "id-modified"}}}
```

Comment: Why are you adding slashes ?

Comment: if you result is a string then you could do `expect(result).toBe(JSON.stringify({"partyRoleIdentifier": {"internalEmployeeIdentifier": {"id": "id-modified"}}}));`

Comment: if result is json then `expect(result).toBe({"partyRoleIdentifier": {"internalEmployeeIdentifier": {"id": "id-modified"}}});`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all you are comparing string to object (`result` is JS object while `expected` is a string). If you wan't to convert JSON string to an object you would need to use JSON.parse function.

```js
let strObj = "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"
// you can't access object properties from string:
strObj.foo // undefined
let obj = {"foo":"bar"}
obj.foo // "bar"
let parsed = JSON.parse(strObj)
parsed.foo // "bar"
```

Secondly, because in JS objects are compared by reference, this code is comparing whether expected and received references point to the same object instance

```js
let a = {foo: "bar"}
let b = {foo: "bar"}
a == b // false
```

In your case use `expect(result).toMatchObject(expected)`. This checks whether object matches the structure and values in expected (performs deep comparison).

As in [jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect.html#tomatchobjectobject)

> Use `.toMatchObject` to check that a JavaScript object matches a subset of the properties of an object. It will match received objects with properties that are not in the expected object.

So in result your code would probably will look like this:

```js
expect(result).toMatchObject({
    partyRoleIdentifier: {
        internalEmployeeIdentifier: {
            id: "id-modified"
        }
    }
})
```